# Compare Two Relations in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I just started studying SQL and this is a demo given by the teacher in an online course and it works fine. The statement is looking for "students such that number of other students with same GPA is equal to number of other students with same sizeHS":

```
select *
from Student S1
where (
    select count(*)
    from Student S2
    where S2.sID <> S1.sID and S2.GPA = S1.GPA
) = (
    select count(*)
    from Student S2
    where S2.sID <> S1.sID and S2.sizeHS = S1.sizeHS
);
```

It seems that in this `where` clause, we're *comparing two relations* (because the result of a subquery is a relation), but most of the time we are comparing attributes(as far as I've seen).

So I'm thinking about **whether there are requirements for how many attributes, and how many tuples, the RELATION should contain when comparing two RELATIONS**. If not, **how do we compare two RELATIONS when there're multiple attributes or multiple tuples and what do we get for result**?
***Note***:

Student relation has **4 attributes: sID, sName, GPA, sizeHS**. And here's the **data**:

```
+-----+--------+-----+--------+
| sID | sName  | GPA | sizeHS |
+-----+--------+-----+--------+
| 123 | Amy    | 3.9 |   1000 |
| 234 | Bob    | 3.6 |   1500 |
| 345 | Craig  | 3.5 |    500 |
| 456 | Doris  | 3.9 |   1000 |
| 567 | Edward | 2.9 |   2000 |
| 678 | Fay    | 3.8 |    200 |
| 789 | Gary   | 3.4 |    800 |
| 987 | Helen  | 3.7 |    800 |
| 876 | Irene  | 3.9 |    400 |
| 765 | Jay    | 2.9 |   1500 |
| 654 | Amy    | 3.9 |   1000 |
| 543 | Craig  | 3.4 |   2000 |
+-----+--------+-----+--------+
```

and the **result** of this query is:

```
+-----+--------+-----+---------+
| sID | sName  | GPA | sizeHS  |
+-----+--------+-----+---------+
| 345 | Craig  | 3.5 |     500 |
| 567 | Edward | 2.9 |    2000 |
| 678 | Fay    | 3.8 |     200 |
| 789 | Gary   | 3.4 |     800 |
| 765 | Jay    | 2.9 |    1500 |
| 543 | Craig  | 3.4 |    2000 |
+-----+--------+-----+---------+
```

Comment: Please limit to one database. What is some  sample data? What output are you expecting? For consistent terminology, databases have rows and columns and {sub}queries.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Is it okay now? Sorry I'm a student and just start learning database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because the result of a subquery is a relation

**Relation** is the scientific name for what we call a table in a database and I like the name "table" much better than "relation". A table is easy to imagine. We know them from our school time schedule for instance. Yes, we relate things here *inside* a table (day and time and the subject taught in school), but we can also relate *tables to tables* (pupils' timetables with the table of class rooms, the overall subject schedule, and the teacher's timetables). As such, tables in an RDBMS are also *related* to each other (hence the name *relational* database management system). I find the name relation for a table quite confusing (and many people use the word "relation" to describe the relations *between* tables instead).

So, yes, a query result itself is again a table ("relation"). And from tables we can of course select:

```
select * from (select * from b) as subq;
```

And then there are scalar queries that return exactly one row and one column. `select count(*) from b` is such a query. While this is still a table we can select from

```
select * from (select count(*) as cnt from b) as subq;
```

we can even use them where we usually have single values, e.g. in the select clause:

```
select a.*, (select count(*) from b) as cnt from a;
```

In your query you have two scalar subqueries in your where clause.

With subqueries there is another distinction to make: we have correlated and non-correlated subqueries. The last query I have just shown contains a non-correlated subquery. It selects the count of b rows for every single result row, no matter what that row contains elsewise. A correlated subquery on the other hand may look like this:

```
select a.*, (select count(*) from b where b.x = a.y) as cnt from a;
```

Here, the subquery is related to the main table. For every result row we look up the count of b rows matching the a row we are displaying via `where b.x = a.y`, so the count is different from row to row (but we'd get the same count for a rows sharing the same y value).

Your subqueries are also correlated. As with the select clause, the where clause deals with one row at a time (in order to keep or dismiss it). So we look at one student S1 at a time. For this student we count other students (S2, `where S2.sID <> S1.sID`) who have the same GPA (`and S2.GPA = S1.GPA`) and count other students who have the same sizeHS. We only keep students (S1) where there are exactly as many other students with the same GPA as there are with the same sizeHS.

---

### UPDATE

As do dealing with multiple tuples as in

```
select *
from Student S1
where (
    select count(*), avg(grade)
    from Student S2
    where S2.sID <> S1.sID and S2.GPA = S1.GPA
) = (
    select count(*), avg(grade)
    from Student S2
    where S2.sID <> S1.sID and S2.sizeHS = S1.sizeHS
);
```

this is possible in some DBMS, but not in SQL Server. SQL Server doesn't know tuples.

But there are other means to achieve the same. You could just add two subqueries:

```
select * from student s1
where (...) = (...) -- compare counts here
and (...) = (...) -- compare averages here
```

Or get the data in the `FROM` clause and then deal with it. E.g.:

```
select *
from Student S1
cross apply
(
    select count(*) as cnt, avg(grade) as avg_grade
    from Student S2
    where S2.sID <> S1.sID and S2.GPA = S1.GPA
) sx
cross apply
(
    select count(*) as cnt, avg(grade) as avg_grade
    from Student S2
    where S2.sID <> S1.sID and S2.sizeHS = S1.sizeHS
) sy
where sx.cnt = sy.cnt and sx.avg_grade = sy.avg_grade;
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. However, I do understand what this statement is doing, and my question is the "=" between two tables(as you said). I understand how we compare attributes but not tables. I'm thinking about whether there are requirements for how many attributes, and how many tuples, the table should contain when comparing two tables. If not, how do we compare two tables when there're multiple attributes or multiple tuples and what do we get for result?

Comment: Okay, so this was easy, because we compare one number with another (the GPA count with the sizeHS count). As to comparing tuples (e.g. `(year, month)`) of two queries instead of single values, this depends on your DBMS. Some can deal well with tuples, others cannot. This: `select 'hello' where (1,2,3) = (1,2,3)` works fine in PostgreSQL and MySQL for instance, but doesn't at all in SQL Server, because SQL Server doesn't know tuples.

Comment: So, if you wanted to only show students when not only the counts, but, say, also the average grade equals, you'd have to find other means in SQL Server. This includes working with sets (e.g. `INTERSECT`) and lookups (via `[NOT] IN` or `[NOT] EXISTS`), or you'd just select the aggregates in the from clause in order to deal with them then. Well, I guess I'd better update my answer with an example...

Comment: Thanks again for your update! Just curious,  what if both the tables on the left and right side of "="  have multiple tuples(what you just explained is "mutiple attributes")? 
For example: 
`select *
from Student S1
where (select * from Student S2
       where S2.sID <> S1.sID and S2.GPA = S1.GPA) =
      (select * from Student S2
       where S2.sID <> S1.sID and S2.sizeHS = S1.sizeHS);`
and the result is 
123|Amy|3.9|1000
456|Doris|3.9|1000
654|Amy|3.9|1000

Comment: When the datasets have multiple rows, you cannot use `=` (and even if you could, that could only mean that one set shall equal the other, i.e. all rows are equal). If we want to know whether there *exists* another student with the same GPA and sizeHS, we can use `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

There are relational [operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database):

- The intersection operator produces the set of tuples that two
  relations share in common. Intersection is implemented in SQL in the
  form of the INTERSECT operator.
- The difference operator acts on two relations and produces the set of tuples from the first relation that do not exist in the second relation. Difference is implemented in SQL in the form of the EXCEPT or MINUS operator.

So, in the context of SQL Server, for example, you can  do:

```
SELECT *
FROM R1 
EXCEPT
SELECT *
FROM R2
```

to get rows in `R1` not included in `R2` and the reverse - to get all differences.

Of course, the attributes must be the same - if not, you need to explicit set the attributes in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this is a demo given by the teacher and it works fine. What I'm confused is the "=" between two relations but not between two attributes.  I'm thinking about whether there are requirements for how many attributes, and how many tuples, the RELATION should contain when comparing two RELATIONS. If not, how do we compare two RELATIONS when there're multiple attributes or multiple tuples and what do we get for result?